# Using Multiple CEWP's on same page only ever displays one

Tags: 2007, web-part

Trying to build a page with multiple graphs. Looking to use Google Code as it is nicer looking than a simple Excel graph set. http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/

The first set of code always works in the CEWP. But it doesn't matter if I add another set of code to the same CEWP or a completely different CEWP on the same page- it never shows up. However, if I were to go back and delete the first set of code while still having the second set in the editor, the second set will now show up.

The problem is the page only ever accepts ONE graphical codeset, no matter the number of CEWPs. How can I add unlimited sets?

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your code with the 2 charts on a page outside of SharePoint and see if you have the same problem. If the error occurs only inside the CEWP, then try putting the code for your web part in a text file and store in a document library on your site. Then, in the CEWP use the "Content link" to provide the location to your text file.

Answer (score 1):

My guess, quickly checking the html that is generated, is that a chart with an  is generated. You should not have two elements with the same ID on your page. Try to generate unique ID's for your placeholder and it should work.